# How do I read all XML nodes of a specific name and put them into an array (or list)?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xpath

I have an XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ticket>
    <comments type="array">
         <comment> 
               <attachments type="array">
                     <attachment>
                          <url>I NEED WHATEVER IS IN HERE</url>
                     </attachment>
               </attachments>
         </comment>
         <comment>
               <attachments type="array">
                     <attachment>
                          <url>I NEED WHATEVER IS IN HERE</url>
                     </attachment>
               </attachments>
         <comment>
     </comments>
</ticket>
```

How would I go about getting whatever is inside the URL tag and add it to a `<List>`? I'm using C#.

Comment: What format are you receiving the Xml as? File, XDocument, XmlDocument, etc?

Comment: var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(client.DownloadString(url));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
var result = XDocument.Parse(inputXml)
    .DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>().Select(e => e.Value).ToList();
```

Or using XPath:

```
var result = ((IEnumerable)XDocument.Parse(input).XPathEvaluate("//text()"))
    .Cast<XText>().ToList();
```

To retrieve text only from `url` element use:

```
var result = XDocument.Parse(inputXml)
        .Descendants("url").Select(e => e.Value).ToList();
```

or change above XPath: `//url/text()`

Comment: I guess a better approach would be to only select the inner text of **url** nodes, just in case other kinds of text nodes are inserted in that XML.

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena, It depends on task. It isn't clear from OP's question. Anyway it is easy to modify provided query.

Comment: var result = XDocument.Parse(inputXml)
        .Descendants("url").Select(e => e.Value).ToList(); is exactly what i was looking for. I <3 you. :D

Answer (score 2):

```
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml_content))
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(sr);

    IList<string> values = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("ticket/comments/attachments/url").Select(e => e.Value).ToList();
}
```

Or, based on your use case in your comment:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml_content);
IList<string> values = doc.SelectNodes("ticket/comments/attachments/url")
    .Cast<XmlElement>().Select(e => e.InnerText).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use                                                                             var values  = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("ticket/comments/attachments/url").InnerXml;