# Lookup from xml file using linq

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq

I want to read a xml file and load as list and look for the value during the form load. How can i read the file and get it as a list???
The Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Types>
<Type>t1-p2</Type>
<Type>t1-k1</Type>
<Type>t2-s2</Type>
</Types>
```

Class File:

```
class Testtypes
    {
        public string Type;

        public static List<Testtypes> getTypes()
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("test.xml");
            var q = doc.Descendants("Type").ToList();
            return getTypes.();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats is the class i have created..

Comment: This question/answer is similar enough to give you an idea of where to go, I think:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280719/how-do-i-read-all-xml-nodes-of-a-specific-name-and-put-them-into-an-array-or-li

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I would *not* have a public field. At least use a property. I'd also rename the class to something a little more meaningful. But you can change your code to:

```
class Testtypes
{
    public string Type { get; private set; }

    public static List<Testtypes> FromXml(string filename)
    {
        return XDocument.Load(filename)
                        .Root.Elements("Type")
                        .Select(x => new Testtypes { Type = x.Value })
                        .ToList();
    }
}
```

Or given that you've only got a string, you could avoid creating your own type:

```
public static List<string> FromXml(string filename)
{
    return XDocument.Load(filename)
                    .Root.Elements("Type")
                    .Select(x => x.Value)
                    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I need a method which should return all the values, so that I can get the value compare it in te GUI. How can i get the values of "Type"??

Comment: @linguini: Um, the code I've given *does* return all the values. You can fetch the `Type` property of any of the returned values.

Comment: Jon Skeet: var x = Testtypes.FromXml().  , this way i'm trying to get the value in gui..but it's not workng.

Comment: @linguini: "It's not working" is *never* a good enough description. I suspect it's because you're not passing in the filename - I extracted it from the method, including it as a parameter instead. It's not a good idea to hard code it in the parsing method.

Comment: @linguini: Well yes, that will fail because you're not passing in the filename. Did the compiler error not make that clear?

Comment: It is `.Load(file)` not `.Parse(file)`.  Parse is used for parsing xml strings.  Also `.Elements()` would be preferable since all the Type nodes are children of the root node.

Comment: @linguini: And again, you say what the code is, but not the error. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @ChuckSavage: With `Elements` you need to explicitly use `Root` of course, but that's fair enough - done.

Answer (score 3):

Parse method receives a ready string where you needed first to read the file.
Use the Load method to read the file and it comes ready to use the Descendants method as follow:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetTypes()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("../../test.xml");
    var xmlElementList = doc.Descendants("Type");
    var stringList = xmlElementList.Select(element => element.Value);

    return stringList;
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
            private static List<TestType> testType;

            public static List<TestType> TestTypes
            {
                get
                {
                    if (testType== null)
                    {
                        var fileName = GetFilePath("TestTypes.xml");

                        testType= DeseriaizeXml<List<TestType>>(fileName);
                    }

                    return testType;
                }
            }



  private static T DeseriaizeXml<T>(String fileName) where T : class
            {
                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
                {
                    return DeseriaizeXml<T>(stream);
                }
            }

            private static T DeseriaizeXml<T>(Stream stream) where T : class
            {
                using (
                    var xmlReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8,
                                                                         new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas(), null))
                {
                    var xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));

                    return xmlSer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as T;
                }
            }

     private static String GetFilePath(String fileName)
        {
            var asmUri = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

            if (asmUri.IsFile)
            {
                var asmFolder = Directory.GetParent(asmUri.LocalPath);

                return Path.Combine(asmFolder.FullName, fileName);
            }

            throw new Exception();
        }
```

Comment: maybe john, but isn't it beautiful? D:D:D: and also, you must have the exact reflection of xml data structure in type

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Load()` method to load a file and then create a new `Testtype` for each value.  Since each Type is a child of the root node, `Elements()` is the one you'd want instead of `Descendants()`.

```
class Testtypes
{
    public string Type;

    public static List<Testtypes> getTypes()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        return doc.Root.Elements("Type")
                   .Select(x => new Testtypes
                   {
                       Type = x.Value
                   }
                   .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If my xml is such simple,I would do this

```
var myList=XElement.Load("data.xml")
                   .DescendantNodes()
                   .Where(N => N.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text);
```